# Update session arraylist using update/delete commands on DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm creating a shopping cart ArrayList which displays through a data grid. 
I've been stuck on this for ages and am not able to find a solution that works without SQL to a database.
The session object contains more data than needs to show in the datagrid, I'm limiting the view to just the essentials.

I've include all the method for both creating and updating that I've got.

```
// Method to create data table and insert onto page
Public Sub createShoppingCartTable()

    Dim tableColumnCode As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnCode
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        .ColumnName = "ProductCode"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnCode)

    Dim tableColumnName As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnName
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        .ColumnName = "Name"
        .DefaultValue = "unknown"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnName)

    Dim tableColumnQuantity As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnQuantity
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        .ColumnName = "Quantity"
        .DefaultValue = "5"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnQuantity)

    Dim tableColumnPrice As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnPrice
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
        .ColumnName = "Price"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnPrice)

    Dim tableColumnTotalPrice As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnTotalPrice
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
        .ColumnName = "TotalPrice"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnTotalPrice)


    //create rows with products added to cart
    Dim localShoppingCart As ArrayList = Session("shoppingCartSession")
    If Not localShoppingCart Is Nothing Then
        Dim tableRow As System.Data.DataRow = ShoppingCartTable.NewRow()
        Dim intMaxRows As Integer = localShoppingCart.Count - 1
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim localObj As New Product()

        For i = 0 To intMaxRows
            localObj = localShoppingCart(i)
            tableRow = ShoppingCartTable.NewRow()
            tableRow("ProductCode") = localObj.itemID
            tableRow("Name") = localObj.itemName
            tableRow("Quantity") = localObj.itemQuantity
            tableRow("Price") = localObj.itemPrice
            tableRow("TotalPrice") = localObj.itemQuantity * localObj.itemPrice
            ShoppingCartTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
        Next
        btnCheckout.Visible = True
        btnContinueShopping.Visible = True

    Else
        btnCheckout.Visible = False
        btnContinueShopping.Visible = False
    End If

    Me.dgDatagrid.DataSource = Me.ShoppingCartTable
    Me.dgDatagrid.DataBind()
End Sub


Private Sub refreshShoppingCart(ByVal selectedIndex As Integer)
    createShoppingCartTable()
    With dgDatagrid
        .DataSource = Me.ShoppingCartTable  
        .EditItemIndex = selectedIndex
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub dgDatagrid_EditCommand(source As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgDatagrid.EditCommand
    refreshShoppingCart(e.Item.ItemIndex)
End Sub


Private Sub dgDatagrid_CancelCommand(source As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgDatagrid.CancelCommand
    refreshShoppingCart(-1)
End Sub


Private Sub dgDatagrid_UpdateCommand(source As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgDatagrid.UpdateCommand
    Dim primaryKey = CType(e.Item.Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim number As Integer = CType(e.Item.Cells(4).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    refreshShoppingCart(-1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't explained the specific issue you're encountering.

Comment: I can't get the selected item in the data grid to link to the session arraylist to then update the quantity

Comment: Explain exactly what you expect to happen and where and how in the code the behaviour differs from what you expect.